# Object variable or with block variable not set trying to run macro from CommandButton

Tags: vba, excel

I've done a summary workbook of some workbooks located in some different drives which I want to update (as they rely on INDIRECT in my workbook) by simply opening the files, and in extension update all values (hopefully). What I've tried is to implement a CommandButton through Developer tab and ActiveX Controls. I then right click this button and "View code" where I simply got "Private Sub CommandButton21_Click" and "End Sub" which I gather means that the "button's name" is CommandButton21.

My code looks like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    Dim WbookCheck As Workbook
    Dim sPath As String, sFile As String

On Error Resume Next
    sPath = "C:\Pathtofile"
    sFile = sPath & "filename.xlsx"
    Set WbookCheck = Workbooks(sFile)
On Error GoTo 0
    If CommandButton21.Value = True Then
        If WbookCheck Is Nothing Then 'Closed
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFile, ReadOnly:=True
        ElseIf Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name = WbookCheck.Name Then
            WbookCheck.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Else
            WbookCheck.Activate
        End If
    Else
        WbookCheck.Close True
    End If
End Sub
```

Does anybody have a clue regarding this?

Comment: At a quick glance, it looks like there needs to be a backslash between the path and filename. Maybe change to: `sPath = "C:\Pathtofile\\`` Does that help?

Comment: This helped in this project as well as in another project so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are trying to test the value of a commandbutton, but it will be False so the attempt to close a workbook variable that was never assigned will fail. You should skip the Value test and use:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    Dim WbookCheck As Workbook
    Dim sPath As String, sFile As String

On Error Resume Next
    sPath = "C:\Pathtofile\"
    sFile = sPath & "filename.xlsx"
    Set WbookCheck = Workbooks(sFile)
On Error GoTo 0

    If WbookCheck Is Nothing Then 'Closed
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFile, ReadOnly:=True
    ElseIf Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name = WbookCheck.Name Then
        WbookCheck.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Else
        WbookCheck.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for being late with a response. I've been occupied with other projects. This works like a charm however! I originally took the code from some website in order to learn VBA. Originally there was no CommandButton I Believe but rather Another type of button, hence the invalid  comparison I believe. Thanks again though!